# How do you create an appointment\reminder in Outlook for the 2nd to last day of the month?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, appointments

I want to have a reminder on the second to last day of each month.  I can do the last day (or weekday) but I want to a reminder the day before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the recurrence to the last day and then in the reminders, select 1 day before.

Comment: Can the reminder work for only weekend days?  If the end of the month is on a Monday, I would need a reminder on Friday, not Sunday.